# Typescript spread `interface` keys as union of strings

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, properties

Is it possible to typecheck a function argument to be one of the `interface`'s keys:

```js
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const updateUserProperty = (property: 'id' | 'email' | 'password') => e =>
  this.setState({ [property]: e.target.value });
```

I'd like `'id' | 'email' | 'password'` not be hardcoded.

In a JS way eg. `IUser` being an object, I can translate that to `Object.keys(IUser).join(' | ')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const updateUserProperty = (property: keyof IUser) => e =>
    this.setState({ [property]: e.target.value });

updateUserProperty("sdsd"); //Error
updateUserProperty("id"); //Ok
```

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html).

Comment: Perfect. Available since: TypeScript 2.1